# Is there a good example of an MVC framework in practice?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I have read hundreds of articles on models, and how they are used in the MVC framework. However, I've had a hard time finding a good example of one being used in the wild.

I feel like seeing something that goes beyond the limits of a tutorial would help me understand the end goal.

Do you know of any open source - and fully functioning - frameworks that I could check out as examples?

NOTE - I'm not looking for simply CodeIgniter - unless it's a site or app that was based on CodeIgniter and therefore has stuff that I didn't download with the CI framework itself.

Comment: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ is the best resource for that.

Comment: I find the examples and tutorials of [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/index.html) pretty good. Next to that the code is easy to read and understand which makes it easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is an open source ecommerce system build upon the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/).